# Best way to handle internet authentication pages within iOS app?

Tags: ios, afnetworking

What is the best way to handle WiFi authentication pages within an iOS app (often found in free WiFi zones, hotels, etc.) such as within Settings.app (displays a web view within a modal when user needs to be authenticated)? I have some ideas for a custom solution such as checking for redirects, content types, and then displaying a web view to the user, but wondering if there is an already implemented pre-existing solution.

**Background:**

iOS 5+ supported

All network requests routed through AFNetworking

Answer (score 2):

I think your intuitions here are good. You should probably do at least four things:

1. Use AFNetworking's [`setRedirectResponseBlock`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setRedirectResponseBlock%3a) and identify when the `request` URL is a different domain than the one you intended.
2. In your [`setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperation.html#//api/name/setCompletionBlockWithSuccess%3afailure%3a) handler blocks, detect errors resulting from status codes not in the 2xx range.
3. You should probably also have a [`setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFURLConnectionOperation.html#//api/name/setWillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallengeBlock%3a) in which you detect unexpected authentication challenges.
4. You might also want to use [`AFNetworkReachabilityManager`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.html) (based upon Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample) to determine the type of connection (e.g. recognize the absence of any current WiFi connection).

Clearly, if the WiFi hotspot requires a WPA2/WPA/WEP password to connect to the hotspot at all (as opposed to hotspots for which there is no WPA2/WPA/WEP authentication, but rather the authentication is challenge-response or some HTML-based authentication), there's not much you can do about that, because as far as AFNetworking knows, you don't have a WiFi connection at all (in which case the fourth technique listed above might be informative). But many (most?) hotspots don't require any password to connect, but redirect you to a HTML-based login page, in which case the above first three techniques might help.

As far as I know, you have to implement this logic yourself.

Comment: I'm just starting to use AFNetworking and @Rob your answer is very helpful so +1. I wanted to make a point regarding your 2nd point above. In my testing  when the status code is in the 4xx or 5xx range I'm getting the failure block called so you may want to check for errors there too.

Comment: @Paul Agreed. You really want to check both blocks that you set with `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:`. I've tried to make that more explicit.